# Unknown quotation marks added to string object in NSMutableArray after for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an array of `NSString` objects, the objects have some unneccessary chars (one object looks like this in the console: `"\"stringContent\""`) that I'm removing with the below code. It works correctly, however when I log `arr1` 50-60% of the strings got a quotation marks like this `"stringContent"`, the others don't have it. Actually my problem is that I don't have an why it happens, because when I log the strings in the for loop they don't have the quotation marks. Do anybody has an idea what can causes this?

```
NSMutableArray * arr1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];

for (NSString *str in self.stringArray) {

    NSString *newString = [str substringToIndex:[brand length]-1];

    NSString *nwstr = [newString substringFromIndex:1];

    [arr1 addObject:nwstr];

    NSLog(@"string %@", nwstr);

}
NSLog(@"array %@", arr1);
```

Other thing that might be helpful, when I call this every object appears in the console, it's like the quotation marks are hidden for the `containsString` method, because a lot of them don't meet the requirement of the if statement.

```
for (NSString *str in arr1) {


    if (![str containsString:@"\""]) {


        NSLog(@"XXX %@", str);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the strings with quotation marks as a group, and those without as a group, can you spot something different about the two groups? What you are seeing is the way the array is formatted for output.

Comment: @CRD nothing, this is how the array looks like: `array (
    "str1",
    str2,
    str3,
    "str4",
    "str5",
    "str6...")`

Comment: Your strings are actually *str1*, *str2*, etc.? I doubt it. What can you see different about *str1*, *str4*, *str5* and *str6* as a group when compared to *str2* and *str3*?

Comment: @CRD No, I used them just as examples. There is nothing that are different between the two groups. It looks like it's totally random, not something based on the string length or its chars.

Comment: Another hint and I'm sure you'd have spotted it yourself. But Hot Licks has spelt it out for you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you NSLog an NSArray or NSDictionary, the elements are displayed in a log format which MAY (or may not) include gratuitous quotation marks, escaped characters, etc. Specifically, quotation marks are used around strings, EXCEPT when the strings contain no non-alphabetic characters or blanks.

**More detail:**  What actually happens is that NSLog internally invokes `[NSString stringWithFormat:]` or one of its kin to format the text to be logged.  `stringWithFormat:`, in turn, invokes the `description` method of each object in the parameter list that corresponds to a `%@` format directive.  It is the `description` method of NSArray and NSDictionary which adds the extra characters.

Comment: It's not just the NSLog, it's the same if I display it in a textview. (The strings contain alphabetic chars only and spaces if the object contain two words)

Comment: @bushiko - The transformation occurs when the *description* method is called on the array/dictionary, which happens by default in NSLog.  One should not normally use *description* for a TextView, so this phenomenon should not be seen then.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not getting it totally. How could I check if the description is used for the TextView or not? I understand that it can happen in NSLog, but the TextView issue not so clear.

Comment: @bushiko - If you are using, eg, `[NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", theArray]` then that will invoke `description`.

Comment: Great, got it, thanks! I tried `textView.text = array[1];` and no quotation marks.